# Adding a warning label or any kind of message when user clicks on show code

Tags: html, css

Assuming I know what browser-version is being used,is it possible for me to add a message when a user tries to see the code or uses the Ctrl U short-cut? Any kind of message is fine. Sorry for being so broad,kind of new to this..

Comment: "is it possible for me to add a message when a user tries to see the code or uses the Ctrl U short-cut?" *why* do you want to do this? It sounds like an XY Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery you can do something like this.

```
$(document).keypress("u",function(e) {
  if(e.ctrlKey)
    alert("Ctrl+u was pressed!!");
});
```

Or native

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.which === 85) {
        alert("Ctrl+u was pressed!!");
    }
});
```

Disable context menu:

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
```

Just an addendum, it's considered unprofessional to attempt to hide your source code. It's also impossible to sheild it from people,
you've already sent them all the data in your HTTP response, anyone with a small amount of knowledge can still see your source.
Consider obfuscating your code if your really want to take measures against theft.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is  there any way to make a message appear when user right clicks and selects Show code?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't meant to be a way to hide my code at all. Just warning that it is completely novice and just wanted to know if it's possible ^^

Comment: No problems, have fun! :) Also please accept answer for others, thanks.